# Im trying to iterate through an array backwards, while doubling every other element and subtracting it by 9 if digit exceeds 9

Tags: javascript

I am currently completing a code challenge through codecademy. Below is the first through fourth steps

Create a function, validateCred() that has a parameter of an array. The purpose of validateCred() is to return true when an array contains digits of a valid credit card number and false when it is invalid. This function should NOT mutate the values of the original array.

To find out if a credit card number is valid or not, use the Luhn algorithm. Generally speaking, an algorithm is a series of steps that solve a problem — the Luhn algorithm is a series of mathematical calculations used to validate certain identification numbers, e.g. credit card numbers. The calculations in the Luhn algorithm can be broken down as the following steps:

1.) Starting from the farthest digit to the right, AKA the check digit, iterate to the left.

2.) As you iterate to the left, every other digit is doubled (the check digit is not doubled). If the number is greater than 9 after doubling, subtract 9 from its value.

3.) Sum up all the digits in the credit card number.

4.) If the sum modulo 10 is 0 (if the sum divided by 10 has a remainder of 0) then the number is valid, otherwise, it’s invalid.

I've been able to iterate through the array -however i havent been able to double every OTHER number within the array as it clearly states it doesnt want the check digit doubled. Also its cutting off the last number in the array - im fairly new to javascript so please go easy on me! Ive asked a similar question earlier but since deleted upon smoothing out my basic knowledge some more.

```
The array in question im referencing

const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];

const validateCred = arr => {
  let reversedArray = []
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) {
      reversedArray.push(arr[i])
    } else if (arr[i] * 2 > 9) {
      reversedArray.push(arr[i] * 2 - 9)
    }else {
      reversedArray.push(arr[i] * 2)
    }
  }
  console.log(reversedArray)
}

console.log(validateCred(valid1))
```

```
Resulting console log:
[ 7, 0, 7, 6, 2, 0, 7, 0, 9, 7, 5, 6, 9, 3, 1 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

First let's iterate through the whole array - since iteration begins from 0, we should include it in the for loop

```
for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Then, the array contains odd number of elements, so the check digit is not included by default for this particular array. You can of course check if it's a 'check' digit (check digit is always the last of the initial array, so i == arr.length - 1), but for this array it is not needed.

You also have a condition, that every other digit is doubled, but in your code you are not doubling the numbers with even digits.
So the if statement will look something like this

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
    if (arr[i] * 2 > 9) {
        reversedArray.push(arr[i] * 2 - 9);

    }
    else {
      reversedArray.push(arr[i] * 2);
    }
}
else {
    reversedArray.push(arr[i]);
}
```

Also, your function is meant to return the reversed array and not return it into console. It is ok to console.log for testing purposes, but most of the code practicing websites only want the end result.

After following changes my resulting array is like this

```
[8, 0, 8, 3, 1, 0, 8, 0, 9, 5, 7, 3, 9, 6, 5, 8]
```

The sum is 80, which divides by 10 without the remainder
P.S. The full code (the check for 'check' is also there) for reference is in the snippet

```js
const valid1 = [4, 5, 3, 9, 6, 7, 7, 9, 0, 8, 0, 1, 6, 8, 0, 8];

const validateCred = arr => {
  let reversedArray = []
  for (let i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (i % 2 == 0 && i != arr.length-1) {
                if (arr[i] * 2 > 9) {
            reversedArray.push(arr[i] * 2 - 9)
        }else {
          reversedArray.push(arr[i] * 2)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        reversedArray.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }

  return reversedArray;
}

console.log(validateCred(valid1))
```